# .htaccess rewrite rule redirecting instead of rewriting url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

This is the content of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.+)? /negocio$2?shopURL=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteOptions Inherit
```

It takes not found directories and transform them into a php variable while retaining the rest of the url. When I go to:

http://lujanventas.com/test/asdf

The address bar shows:

```
http://lujanventas.com/negocio/?shopURL=asdf
```

(It should still show: "http://lujanventas.com/test/asdf")

What am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried removing the QSA flag?

Comment: I just tried. It seems it works exactly as before.

Comment: What is "the URL that was typed initially" supposed to mean?

Comment: When I go to: `http://lujanventas.com/test/asdf` I want to see that URL not '/negocio/?shopURL=asdf'.

Comment: Is `/negocio` an actual directory that exists?

Comment: yes, if you go to: http://lujanventas.com/test/dztecnologias you can see how it's redirecting to http://lujanventas.com/negocio/?shopURL=dztecnologias and the page is working correctly. The only problem is with the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by adding a `/` after the 2.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.+)? /negocio$2/?shopURL=$1 [L,QSA]
```